# Translating Lat/Lon coordinates to X,Y plane, with control points

Tags: geolocation, geometry

I have an arbitrary map image, which may or may not be accurately projected to some standard geographic mapping. Probably not, though, since it's an artists rendition. Consider this map a 2D image of pixels at 0,0 onward.

I'd like to map lat/lon points in world space to this map. Since the map is not necessarily a known or accurate projection, I've got to come up with some other solution. I figure that establishing control points on the 2D image that correlate to known lat/lon values is step #1. At a minimum, 3, but maybe more, in case it's required to sort out distortion in the map image.

What algorithm or equation would I be looking for to take these control points, and identify the X,Y position on the image from any given lat/lon input?

I expect it to be inaccurate, depending on the number of control points. And I expect, for some weirder images, to have to go and add many control points in certain areas to make it line up right.

Comment: What sort of size is the area depicted? Is it contained in a square with size a few km? A few tens of km? Hundreds of km? The larger the area, the more difficult the problem as for larger areas you need to take the curvature of the earth into account.

Comment: Probably less than half a mile. Distortion isn't a concern.

Answer (score 0):

When the area depicted is small, (e.g. it fits in a square few km on the side), one thing to try is described below. I'm sorry if you find the description too terse, I wanted to keep it reasonably short.

The idea is to assume the image is in some unknown conformal projection, and to try to approximate it. Of course this may fail, if the image can not, in fact, be reasonably approximated this way.

Given your control points P[], project them into map coordinates Q[] using some conformal projection, and get hold of their image coordinates R[]. To within a metre or so -- given the assumption above -- the R[] can be obtained from the Q[] by a transformation T that is a translation, an (isotropic) scaling and a rotation. You can then find T, say by least squares, using the Q[] and R[]. You have a two stage map from the control point geographic coordinates P[] to their image coordinates R[]: first project using the chosen projection, then apply T. You could use the inverse of this map to go from arbitrary image coordinates to geographical coordinates.

If the image is larger than a few km, you may not get enough accuracy this way. All is not lost. Though a translation, scale and rotation may not suffice, any two conformal projections are related by a (complex) analytic map. So you could try to fit (an approximation to) this map using the control points as above. A suitable approximation might be a complex polynomial, or a complex rational function.

If I were doing this, I think I would first test it on artificial data. For example you could generate images of various sizes, using some projection (differing from the one used above), and see how well you fit the known points in these images.